# Skip Column 'Name' does not belong to table

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create method for inserting values from DataTable to my list from any table that this method accepts even if required column does not exist in table. If value is empty or doesn't exist, it needs to be relapsed by 0.

My code:

```
List<int> Features = new List<int>();
foreach (DataRow r in DataTable.Rows)
{ 
     Features.Add(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(r["Id"].ToString()) ? Convert.ToInt32(r["Id"]) : 0);
}
```

I have a problem when the column doesn't exist. I get an error

> Column 'Id' does not belong to table Table1

What can I do to get my code to work even if there is no column "Id"?

Comment: You can check `r.Table.Columns.Contains("Id")`

Comment: Why the <sql> tag? (I see no SQL.)